# Rails 3.1 associations and counting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations

I have two models in my Rails application, Users and Calls.
The model associations are set as follows:

**user model**

```
has_many  :calls
```

**call model**

```
belongs_to  :user
```

I am trying to call, within the application.html.erb layout, the number of calls that the current user has.

Currently, I am using the following string:

```
 <%= Call.count %>
```

Which works but it's obviously counting *all* calls, not just the calls that the current user has.

So I swapped that for the following:

```
<%= current_user.Call.calls.count %>
```

I am confused as to how to do this. I need to be able to call the count from anywhere so I can then start working on counting based on the last 30 days etc.

Comment: Also note that Call is a potentially bad name for a model since "call" is a ruby method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really want to be putting database calls within views, you really want to put that into a controller. You'd be looking for something like `User.find(current_user.id).calls.count` as this will then use the association of which you've set up, or if you want to disregard the model relation you could do `Call.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count`

So put the below into the relevant controller (in the correct action), and likewise for the view.

Controller

`@count = Call.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count`

View

`<%= @count %>`

Comment: I've added this to my Call model `def callcount
    Call.where(:user_id => current_user.id).count
  end` and called it from the view with `<%= Call.callcount %>`, it's not working - what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
current_user.calls.count
```

You can do the same thing with any User object:

```
user = User.find(1)
user.calls.count
```

You then can chain more conditions to do the date-based counts:

```
user.calls.where("calls.created_at > ?", 30.days.ago).count
```